# Fonction du pronom « en » dans « j'en conviens »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Quand on dit « j'en conviens », on veut dire « je conviens *de* quelque chose » en faisant référence à ce qui a été mentionné antérieurement.

Exemple :

> Tu conviens de ton erreur ? Oui, j'en conviens.

Ma déduction grammaticale en ce qui concerne « j'en conviens » est-elle correcte ou non ?

Comment: Si ma déduction grammaticale en ce qui concerne _j'en conviens_ est correcte ou non.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est tout à fait cela. *Nous convenons de quelque chose*, aussi *nous en convenons*, *en* s'appliquant à la chose en question.

Le [sens III. A. de la définition de *convenir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenir), dans le TLF, donne de nombreux exemples.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Your _tout à fait_ has fully eased my grammatical mind.

Comment: C'est utilisation de *en* n'est pas particulière, c'est la plus courante : remplacer un groupe introduit par une préposition *de* ou le partitif *de*.

Comment: On devrait modifier le titre de la question. Que penses-tu de "fonction du pronom « en » dans « j'en conviens »" ?

Answer (score 1):

Le petit Robert donne des exemples d'utilisation pour *convenir **de*** synonyme de *avouer, concéder, confesser* dans le sens de *dire, reconnaître* :

> - "Je suis un âne, il est vrai, j'en conviens, je l'avoue." *La Fontaine*
> - Elle ne veut pas convenir de son erreur.
> - Vous devriez en convenir.
> - Il en a convenu.
> - "J'ai convenu de mon tort de trop  bonne grâce." *Rousseau*
> - "Une tristesse dont il n'eût jamais convenu." *Mauriac*

N.B. : *convenir **que*** a pour synonyme *admettre* [sans culpabilité
induite]).

---

**AJOUT** *suite au commentaire*
*grâce* : "Aide de Dieu" ; Les *bonnes grâces* de quelqu'un : les faveurs qu'il accorde, ses dispositions favorables (extraits du petit Robert).

> Nous accepterons de *bonne grâce* toute critique raisonnée et suggestion constructive de ceux qui auront bien voulu utiliser ce volume. (*[wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_bonne_gr%C3%A2ce)*)

On pourrait alors compléter :

> Mais nous aurons le sentiments d’avoir mis en avant de **trop** *bonne grâce* notre ouverture à la critique si nous devenons être l’objet de critiques ad hominem ou de suggestion hors de propos.

Le *trop* indique donc que la faveur accordée n’a pas été reçue telle qu’elle devait l’être, mais a été trahie par une attitude méprisante, mal intentionnée, de mauvaise foi ; qu'il y perte de réciprocité, d'égalité, de respect.

Comment: Vous avez cité Rousseau : *Ne reparlons plus de cela, je vous prie ; j'ai convenu de mon tort de **trop bonne grâce**, pour que vous deviez vous en souvenir.* Pourriez-vous expliciter le sens de **« trop bonne grâce »** ? À propos de **« ... bonne grâce »**, je me suis déjà référé à http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2637997.

Comment: @LePressentiment Faute de place, j'ai placé le commentaire dans la réponse. J'ai essayé de le mettre en perspective en tenant compte du *pour que vous deviez vous en souvenir* de J.-J.Rousseau .

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, since your question is about the usage of «en», here is another example to clarify your thoughts

> Qu'est-ce que tu *en* penses? On va en Bretagne ou en Normandie?

The *en* (in *italics*) is what *refers* to something (in the spirit of «de quelques chose») whereas the non-italics ones are prepositions.